# Puppeth: No ethstats server configured

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-authority, poa, puppeth

**Update**

This is an issue with Docker Compose >= 1.23.0 and I've raised this in the [go-ethereum GitHub issues tracker](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18086).

---

I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/@collin.cusce/using-puppeth-to-manually-create-an-ethereum-proof-of-authority-clique-network-on-aws-ae0d7c906cce) to create my own private blockchain using PoA consensus.

But I have problem at the creating Ethstats section. Seems like my controller server is not able to communicate with the server that is hosting the ethstats container.

Logs:

```
$ ./go-ethereum/build/bin/puppeth
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Welcome to puppeth, your Ethereum private network manager |
|                                                           |
| This tool lets you create a new Ethereum network down to  |
| the genesis block, bootnodes, miners and ethstats servers |
| without the hassle that it would normally entail.         |
|                                                           |
| Puppeth uses SSH to dial in to remote servers, and builds |
| its network components out of Docker containers using the |
| docker-compose toolset.                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

Please specify a network name to administer (no spaces or hyphens, please)
> mypoa

Sweet, you can set this via --network=mypoa next time!

INFO [11-11|21:01:33.260] Administering Ethereum network           name=mypoa
INFO [11-11|21:01:33.263] No remote machines to gather stats from

What would you like to do? (default = stats)
 1. Show network stats
 2. Manage existing genesis
 3. Track new remote server
 4. Deploy network components
> 4

What would you like to deploy? (recommended order)
 1. Ethstats  - Network monitoring tool
 2. Bootnode  - Entry point of the network
 3. Sealer    - Full node minting new blocks
 4. Explorer  - Chain analysis webservice (ethash only)
 5. Wallet    - Browser wallet for quick sends
 6. Faucet    - Crypto faucet to give away funds
 7. Dashboard - Website listing above web-services
> 1

Which server do you want to interact with?
 1. Connect another server
> 1

What is the remote server's address ([username[:identity]@]hostname[:port])?
> xx.xxx.xx.xxx

The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22 (xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22)' can't be established.
SSH key fingerprint is b3:21:f9:fa:29:0b:51:80:51:56:31:5d:a5:0c:a5:da [MD5]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Which port should ethstats listen on? (default = 80)
> 8080

Allow sharing the port with other services (y/n)? (default = yes)
> n

What should be the secret password for the API? (must not be empty)
> XYabwCkEZpE823cKHz39KWveOCnbP975Q8v5nTflcS8EWL1rFQ
Building ethstats
Step 1/2 : FROM puppeth/ethstats:latest
latest: Pulling from puppeth/ethstats
Digest: sha256:1728c03555d3327f68be924116eed9f9de56671949c21505f4b78518f06e687e
Status: Downloaded newer image for puppeth/ethstats:latest
 ---> fb62abe59cb2
Step 2/2 : RUN echo 'module.exports = {trusted: ["xx.xxx.xx.xxx"], banned: [], reserved: ["yournode"]};' > lib/utils/config.js
 ---> Running in b034ab7d1f2e
Removing intermediate container b034ab7d1f2e
 ---> a46469df9416
Successfully built a46469df9416
Successfully tagged mypoa/ethstats:latest
Creating mypoa_ethstats_1_d96be358e56e ... done
INFO [11-11|21:02:19.148] Starting remote server health-check      server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
+---------------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
|    SERVER     |    ADDRESS    | SERVICE | CONFIG | VALUE |
+---------------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
| xx.xxx.xx.xxx | xx.xxx.xx.xxx |         |        |       |
+---------------+---------------+---------+--------+-------+

What would you like to do? (default = stats)
 1. Show network stats
 2. Manage existing genesis
 3. Manage tracked machines
 4. Deploy network components
> 4

What would you like to deploy? (recommended order)
 1. Ethstats  - Network monitoring tool
 2. Bootnode  - Entry point of the network
 3. Sealer    - Full node minting new blocks
 4. Explorer  - Chain analysis webservice (ethash only)
 5. Wallet    - Browser wallet for quick sends
 6. Faucet    - Crypto faucet to give away funds
 7. Dashboard - Website listing above web-services
> 2
ERROR[11-11|21:02:40.828] No ethstats server configured

What would you like to do? (default = stats)
 1. Show network stats
 2. Manage existing genesis
 3. Manage tracked machines
 4. Deploy network components
>
```

My cloud setup is exactly like in the article. 1 controller server + 3 node servers with the same Security Group settings like in the article.

Additional note:

I'm able to SSH into the server that is hosting the ethstats container from my controller server.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: For others landing on this question, it is being tracked at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18086